Apollo Gateway doesn't connect to other services inside Docker
I am running 2 GrapQL APIs inside my project and have a Apollo Gateway that connects them. When I run the docker compose file, the APIs get built and work (I can access them through the browser) but for some reason the gateway service doesn't connect to them.
I have seen this issue be posted here, most often the fix is that the Gateway service points to "http://localhost:port/graphql" instead of "http://service:port/graphql" but I have tried that and I still get this error:

gateway   | Error: Couldn't load service definitions for "images" at
http://images:3000: request to http://images:3000/ failed, reason:
connect ECONNREFUSED 172.25.0.4:3000

This is the current log, I have also tried with adding /graphql inside the gateway app.modules file
Things I have tried:

Add a custom network to my docker compose
run docker exec into my gateway and ping the other services by their name, which is registering so that means they are recognized by the gateway service

Commands I use to start the services locally (while in the root of the project)

pnpm start:dev images <- runs image service
pnpm start:dev products <- runs product image
pnpm start:dev <- runs gateway

Here are my Dockerfile for each service:
 FROM node:18-alpine
 
 WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 
 RUN npm install -g pnpm
 
 COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./
 
 RUN pnpm install
 
 COPY . .
 
 EXPOSE 3000

 CMD ["pnpm", "start:dev", "images"]

Docker compose file:
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/db-data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ${PWD}/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

  images:
    container_name: images
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/images/Dockerfile
      args:
        - SERVICE_NAME=images
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - database
    

  products:
    container_name: products
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/products/Dockerfile
      args:
        - SERVICE_NAME=products
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - database

  gateway:
    container_name: gateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/gateway/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    environment:
      - PRODUCTS_HOST=products:3001
      - IMAGES_HOST=images:3000
    depends_on:
      - database
      - products
      - images


volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local

Gateway app.module.ts:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { ApolloGatewayDriver, ApolloGatewayDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/apollo';
import { IntrospectAndCompose } from '@apollo/gateway';

const productsHost = process.env['PRODUCTS_HOST'] || 'localhost:3001';
const imagesHost = process.env['IMAGES_HOST'] || 'localhost:3000';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloGatewayDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloGatewayDriver,
      server: {
        csrfPrevention: false,
      },
      gateway: {
        supergraphSdl: new IntrospectAndCompose({
          subgraphs: [
            {
              name: 'images',
              url: `http://${imagesHost}`,
            },
            {
              name: 'products',
              url: `http://${productsHost}`,
            },
          ],
        }),
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

And here is proof when I run docker ps:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
6f81e45e1d49   gateway-gateway    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   38 seconds ago   Up 37 seconds   0.0.0.0:3002->3002/tcp, :::3002->3002/tcp   gateway
cf77b2cd277b   gateway-products   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   38 seconds ago   Up 37 seconds   0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp, :::3001->3001/tcp   products
f02de42daed3   gateway-images     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   38 seconds ago   Up 37 seconds   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp   images
77e194ce3169   postgres:latest    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   38 seconds ago   Up 37 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   database


Can you directly call http://localhost:3000/ from the host machine (not necessarily expecting anything back, but do you get an HTTP response)?  How do the individual servers set up their network listeners (in the code)?

When I call it through the browser without specifying the /graphql in the url I can't access it

@DavidMaze Right now my images service is on http://localhost:3000/graphql. When I try to run curl: curl http://localhost:3000/graphql
I get:
{"errors":[{"message":"This operation has been blocked as a potential Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF). Please either specify a 'content-type' header (with a type that is not one of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, text/plain) or provide a non-empty value for one of the following headers: x-apollo-operation-name, apollo-require-preflight\n","extensions":
But I have a csrfPrevention false in my gateway service

Here is the images.module.ts file:
@Module({
imports: [
GraphQLModule.forRoot({
driver: ApolloFederationDriver,
autoSchemaFile: {
federation: 2,
},
}),
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
//Would normally be in enironment
type: 'postgres',
...
synchronize: true,
}),
TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ImageEntity]),
],
providers: [ImagesResolver, ImagesService, ProductsResolver],
})
export class ImagesModule {}

And the main.ts
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ImagesModule } from './images.module';
async function bootstrap() {
const app = await NestFactory.create(ImagesModule);
await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
